# Is TestFlight Distribution Available to Apple Enterprise Developer Accounts?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, testflight

I've been using Apple's new TestFlight since it first became available and have had a relatively positive experience with it.  I've always used it with my standard $99 Developer account.

A new client has an Enterprise Program account.  When I've attempted to submit the build to iTunes Connect, I've received the attached error message.  [image: Error Message]

I know that we originally had to export all of our provision profiles again to get the new "beta-reports-active" entitlement.  I've tried that with the client's Enterprise developer account, and it is not added.

To sanity check, I tried to upload the app to my personal developer account and it went as smoothly as always.  No issues.

So, the question is...  Can Enterprise Development Program users deploy an App to TestFlight for internal testing, or does that require a basic developer account.  That would actually make sense to me because one of the points behind the Enterprise program is not having to go through Apple's iTunes Connect and App Store processes.  I just haven't been able to find anything official about it.

Any help or insight is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the official "App Distribution Guide" guide, page "[Distributing Apple Developer Enterprise Program Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html)"

> Important: As a member of the Apple Developer Enterprise Program, you
>   don’t have an iTunes Connect account or the ability to distribute your
>   app for beta testing using iTunes Connect.

It means that an Apple Developer Enterprise account can't be used for beta distribution on TestFlight (iTunes Connect).

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the reference.